# VueJS - How to customize a vue-slider-component's slider bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-slider-component

I am new to Vue js and I am working with the vue-slider-component.
I want to design the slider in a triangular form like below.

[image]

I want to know how to customize the slider bar into this particular shape. Thanks in advance.

```
        <vue-slider
          v-model="SliderValue"
          @change="SliderChange"
          class="horizontal-slider"
          :dotSize="45"
          width="300px"
          height="13px"
          :max="100"
          :min="0"
        />
```

Comment: I don't think you can customise the style of the slider as you want with that package.
If you can't build it by yourself, you could try using this one 
https://github.com/vueform/slider
which offers more flexibility with css variables

Comment: Thanks @Abregre, this was helpful. This gave me a direction to style the slider bar.